# Return a string from a VBA function

Tags: vba

I am following a tutorial and get a compile error at the hello world example function.

What's wrong here?

[image]

Here is the code I tried:

```
Function hi()
    hi = "hello world"
End Function`
```

edit: suggested declarations didn't help
[image]

edit: getting closer. brackets seem to be a problem when calling "hi()"
[image]

Comment: either `Function hi() As String` , or you need to declare `hi` somewhere. Why do you need a `Function` ? why not a regular `Sub` ?

Comment: thanks Shai Rado.
i am not yet selecting function or sub for  a particular reason. first i need to find out how thy work :( see the edited original post, a added 2 images of my error

Comment: Calling a function with parenthesis will return an object, so it's expecting s=hi() or call hi to just run

Comment: thanks, i guess that's it. sorry for wasting your time on such stuff.

Comment: If you want to call your function from the Immediate pane and print the output then you need to call it like this : `? hi()`  (same as `Debug.Print hi()`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use 2 ways to implement your "Hello World" example.

**Option 1:** Simple and good enough for your example, using a regular `Sub` :

```
Sub Hi_()

Dim HiStr   As String

HiStr = "Hello World"
MsgBox HiStr

End Sub
```

---

**Option 2:** Using a `Function` with "Hello World" example:

```
Function Hi(TestHi As String) As String

' Input: this function receives a string as a parameter
' Output: returns a string

Hi = "Test Function with " & TestHi

End Function
```

Now we need a `Sub` to test the `Function`:

```
Sub Test_Hi_Function()

Dim TstHiFunc As String

' send "Hello World" to Function Hi as a parameter
' TstHiFunc gets the returned string result 
TstHiFunc = Hi("Hello World")

' for debug only
MsgBox TstHiFunc

End Sub
```